# Print the array objects inside another array into a specific format in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Generate an array of objects in a format from an array of objects inside another array .

The Given array is :

```
let target =
[[{key: "subscriber_id", value: "1"},
{key: "msisdn_value", value: "2"}],
[{key: "subscriber_id", value: "3"},
{key: "msisdn_value", value: "4"}
]]
```

The expected array of objects should be :

```
result = [
  {"subscriber_id":"1","msisdn_value":"2"},
  {"subscriber_id":"3","msisdn_value":"4"},
]
```

Comment: Please paste your current code implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested `map` calls with `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.values` for a clean and concise solution like so:

```
const result = target.map(e => Object.fromEntries(e.map(Object.values)));
```

Or, for a more efficient solution, use `reduce`:

```
const result = target.map(e => e.reduce((a, { key, value }) => (a[key] = value, a), {}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and destructuring

```js
let target = [[{key: "subscriber_id",value: "1"},{key: "msisdn_value",value: "2"}],[{key: "subscriber_id",value: "3"},{key: "msisdn_value",value: "4"}]]

let final = target.map(data => {
  let [{key:a,value:b},{key:c,value:d}] = data
  return { [a]:b, [c]:d }
})

console.log(final)
```

Loop through each element if there are more than two elements in inner arrays

```js
let target = [[{key: "subscriber_id",value: "1"},{key: "msisdn_value",value: "2"}],[{key: "subscriber_id",value: "3"},{key: "msisdn_value",value: "4"},{key: "key",value: "value"}]]

let final = target.map((data) => {
  return data.reduce((obj,{key,value})=>{
    obj[key] = value 
    return obj
  },{})
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: What if there's more than two key/value pairs? Nobody wants to copy/paste more code, and it'll be extremely WET. `reduce` is better in this case.